# How to apply part of this regular expression to all alternatives?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write a regex that contains either the words “wind”, “temp”, or “press” followed by a non-digit.

So far I have:

```
var regex = /wind|temp|press[^0-9]{0,}/;
```

This doesn’t work because the `[^0-9]{0,}` is with “press”. How would I separate them so that all the words would be read followed by a non digit?

Comment: To experiment with regex you can use https://regex101.com

Comment: Just FYI, regex has `*` which you can use instead of `{0,}` and `\D` for matching non-digits.

Comment: @4castle Be careful with replacing `[^0-9]` by `\D`, as some regex flavors have different semantics for those, as `\D` also doesn’t match arabic numerals like `٢`.

Comment: @Xufox In JS, `\d` is identical to `[0-9]` & `\D` is identical to `[^0-9]`

Comment: @4castle I know. I said _“some regex flavors have different semantics”_.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a (non-capturing) group:

```
var regex = /(?:wind|temp|press)[^0-9]{0,}/;
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a none capturing group to separates those words from the rest of your pattern. Use this pattern:

```
/(?:wind|temp|press)\D*/
```

By the way `{0,}` is the same as `*` in this case. Also if being a non-digit character is mandatory, you probable want to use `+` instead. *(I mean if one of those words **must** be followed by at least one or more non-digit character, then use `+`)*

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE1iW1/1)